# AWS Redshift: Why does DELETE operator use Hash Join instead of Merge Join

Tags: join, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to understand why the AWS Redshift creates different plans between query 1 & 2.

Query 1 => is a select query involving inner join on "id" column, which is distribution and sort key for both tables

Query 2 => is a delete query using the same tables and "id" column.

The issue is for Query 1, Redshift does a merge join but for Query 2 Redshift does a hash join. I checked the Redshift documentation but couldn't find any reason for this happening.

1. Can someone explain this or is the expected behavior ?
2. I read that Hash Joins are more expensive than Merge joins. So are there any best practices to optimize a `UPDATE` query

Here are the queries ->

```
query 1=>  explain select staging.id  from staging inner join request on  staging.id = bid_request.id;
                                      QUERY PLAN                                    
----------------------------------------------------------------
XN Merge Join DS_DIST_NONE  (cost=0.00..941165.11 rows=1 width=400)
Merge Cond: (("outer".id)::text = ("inner".id)::text)
->  XN Seq Scan on request  (cost=0.00..752932.08 rows=75293208 width=44)
->  XN Seq Scan on staging  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=400)


query 2=> explain delete from staging using request where  staging.id = request.id;
                                     QUERY PLAN                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XN Hash Join DS_DIST_NONE  (cost=941165.10..941165.87 rows=1 width=6)
Hash Cond: (("outer".id)::text = ("inner".id)::text)
->  XN Seq Scan on staging  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=406)
->  XN Hash  (cost=752932.08..752932.08 rows=75293208 width=44)
     ->  XN Seq Scan on request  (cost=0.00..752932.08 rows=75293208 width=44)
```